# Apache2.4.20 Compilation error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl and -lcrypto

Tags: docker, compilation, openssl, apache2, dockerfile

I'm currently busy with a bachelor project regarding the differences between webservers. In order to detect those, I am trying to set up a collection of Docker containers. Currently, I'm already having a handful of Nginx servers compiled from source up and running. However, the same with Apache seems to be a challenge. I'm not experienced with compilation at all, apart from the Nginx dockerfiles.

I'm trying to compile apache 2.4.20 from source using OpenSSL 1.0.2.

I tried the following dockerfile (which did work for Apache 2.4.39 with a different OpenSSL version):

```
FROM debian

# Install build requirements (or grab from docker cache)
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install wget git subversion make \
libpcre3-dev \
libpcre++-dev \
libxml2-dev \
libexpat1-dev \
python \
autoconf \
libtool-bin \
libpcre3-dev -y && \
git clone https://github.com/apache/httpd.git


ENV OPENSSL_VERSION=1.0.2   
ARG OPENSSL_VERSION

ENV APACHE_VERSION=2.4.20
ARG APACHE_VERSION

# Install APACHE

# RUN wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/httpd-${APACHE_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
# tar zxf httpd-${APACHE_VERSION}.tar.gz && \

RUN wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-${OPENSSL_VERSION}.tar.gz && tar xzvf openssl-${OPENSSL_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
cd openssl-${OPENSSL_VERSION} && ./Configure linux-x86_64 shared -fpic && make && make install && \
rm -rf /*.tar.gz


RUN cd /httpd && git checkout tags/${APACHE_VERSION} && svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/apr/apr/trunk srclib/apr && ./buildconf
RUN cd httpd && ./configure \
--enable-dav \
--enable-so \
--enable-maintainer-mode \
--prefix=/usr/local/apache2 \
--with-mpm=worker \
--enable-layout=Apache \
--enable-mods-shared=most \
--with-included-apr \
--enable-static-support \
--enable-ssl=static \
--with-ssl=../openssl-${OPENSSL_VERSION} && \  
make && \
make install

# Remove build dependencies
RUN apt-get remove wget git subversion make \
libpcre3-dev \
libpcre++-dev \
libxml2-dev \
python \
autoconf \
libtool-bin \
libpcre3-dev -y && \
apt-get autoremove -y && \
rm -rf /httpd

# Copy SSL certs and configs
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/apache2/ssl && rm -f /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf && rm -f /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
COPY ./shared/apache/apache.crt /usr/local/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
COPY ./shared/apache/apache.key /usr/local/apache2/ssl/apache.key
COPY ./shared/apache/conf/httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
COPY ./shared/apache/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

CMD ["./usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd","-DFOREGROUND"]
```

I've got the following error executing the `make` command in the httpd directory.

```
/httpd/srclib/apr/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -pthread -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security   -L/openssl-1.0.2/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lcrypt -lrt -lpthread -ldl -lexpat  \
         -o ab -static ab.lo       /httpd/srclib/apr/libapr-2.la -lcrypt -lrt -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lexpat -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:73: recipe for target 'ab' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory '/httpd/support'
make[2]: *** [ab] Error 1
```

I tried older and newer openssl versions, but that didn't matter. Newer versions threw deprecated warnings (which where thrown as errors by the compiler) earlier in the compilation process. Older versions gave me the same error, or when they were really old, about missing methods.

I've also tried to install `libssl-dev` as suggested in another thread, that also didn't work.

Any help or tips are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building your custom OpenSSL version, but you are not adding the path where you install openssl (most likely /usr/local) to your LDFLAGS. I think `--with-ssl=/usr/local` should fix your issues

Comment: The `./configure` command has the following parameter: `--with-ssl=../openssl-${OPENSSL_VERSION}`. This should include the custom openSSL

Comment: But this is not the directory where you installed your custom SSL, that is the build directory

Comment: Ahaa. I'm sorry, my bad! Thanks a lot!